# Why do we say оно моё имя for "it's my name" instead of это моё имя?

Tags: выбор-слова

оно моё имя just doesn't make intuitive sense to me. Is it correct to use оно in this case?

Comment: we don't, nobody says anything like that, so either your question is wrong or it needs to be edited.

Comment: In fact, even if you translate "it's my name" word-by-word, you'll get "это есть моё имя". So I cannot even imagine who are those "we" that say "оно моё имя".

Comment: Show the whole sentence or dialog, otherwise it's impossible to understand what's said.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not correct.

Where you probably got this from (at least it's the only possible source I can think of) is the way the concept of noun gender is introduced early on at Russian schools. Before schoolchildren know their way around the formal designations of "masculine", "feminine", and "neuter", they're taught to check which form of **он** and **мой** they would intuitively use with the noun in question. **Он, мой дядя**, **она, моя соль** or **оно, моё такси** is a formula most people remember from school, and might occasionally still use as a quick colloquial way to refer to a noun's gender.

There's a bit of predictable randomness in that you've (presumably) heard it used with **имя**, it being one of the ten surviving neuter nouns with that complicated paradigm that don't even look neuter. **Оно, моё имя** doesn't mean "it's my name"; in fact, it barely means anything, much like "I, me, mine" or "go, went, gone".

Answer (score 1):

Actually, we never use "It's my name" neither in English, nor Russian when we are introducing ourselves.
To introduce yourself, you should say "Меня зовут ...".
For example, "Меня зовут Иван" - "I'm called Ivan"(Means actually "My name is Ivan", but we never use such in Russian).

Comment: Why do you think the question is about introducing oneself?

Comment: Russian is my mothertounge. And I can't imagine the situation, where we say "оно моё имя". So, I throught that this would be helpful for him.